# C# datagridview mouse click event only certain column

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have working code on a datagridview mouse click event but ı want to working this code clicking only third columns of datagridview . Can you help me

Comment: So where is your code?

Comment: There is no problem with code it is working clicking  on the datagridview @saman Gholami

Comment: private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex.Equals(2) && e.RowIndex != -1){
        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell != null && dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value != null)
            MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString());   
}

Answer (score 2):

Although you haven't provided any details, maybe this code helps you to get some hints:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 2) // third-column 
            {
                // when third cell clicked
            }
        }
```